# Multiple lines of text with time stamps. Append the time stamp from each string to the end of each line (so it's twice on each line)

Tags: javascript

Example string:

```
03:47:06 This is line 1
03:47:07 This is line 2
03:47:08 This is line 3
03:47:09 This is line 4
This is line 5
03:47:10 This is line 6
03:47:11 This is line 7
This is line 8
```

I need it to be:

```
03:47:06 This is line 1 03:47:06
03:47:07 This is line 2 03:47:07
03:47:08 This is line 3 03:47:08
03:47:09 This is line 4 03:47:09
This is line 5
03:47:10 This is line 6 03:47:10
03:47:11 This is line 7 03:47:11
This is line 8
```

I'm trying to take the time stamp from any line in the string that has it and append it to the end of the line.

So far, this is what I have:

```
let dateTime = /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/;\n
var timestamps = big_string.match(/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/g);\n
var arrayLength = timestamps.length
for (var x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++) {
console.log(timestamps[x]);

var big_string_array = big_string.split("\n");
var arrayLength2 = big_string_array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength2; i++) {
var log_end = screenrec_log_array[i].replace(/$/gm, "!!!!" + timestamps[x]);
console.log(log_end)
}
}
```

This appends a time stamp to the end of every line, but it seems to go out of sync. I think this is because the string has some lines that don't have a time stamp. My guess is there needs to be an if statement with the loop that adds "!!!1" + timestamps[x]... but I'm struggling to get it to work.

I tried adding

```
if screenrec_log_array.includes(timestamps[x]){
var log_end = screenrec_log_array[i].replace(/$/gm, "!!!!" + timestamps[x]);
console.log(log_end)
}
}
}
```

But I get a Unexpected identifier error

Rather than fixing that bug, maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way, and there is a better method to take the time stamp from the start of any line that has it and append the same line with it again.

Comment: Have a single loop (where you split into lines) and put your matching logic inside the loop. No reason for nested loops for this.

Comment: How would you include an if statement in there? I'm trying to get it to say, if the line contains `/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/g` then replace that line with the time stamp at the start of that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you just need a single loop, with your matching logic within it.

**Example:**

```
var lines, dateTime,i,l,dT;

// example data
lines = `03:47:06 This is line 1
03:47:07 This is line 2
03:47:08 This is line 3
03:47:09 This is line 4
This is line 5
03:47:10 This is line 6
03:47:11 This is line 7
This is line 8`;

// pattern to match for
dateTime = /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/;

// split the lines into an array
lines = lines.split('\n');

// for each line... 
for (i=0,l=lines.length; i<l; i++) {
    // match for the pattern.
    dT = lines[i].match(dateTime);
    // If found, append to end of line. 
    if (dT&&dT[0]) lines[i] += ' ' + dT[0];
}

// put back together
lines = lines.join('\n');

// example output:
console.log(lines);
```

**Output:**

```
03:47:06 This is line 1 03:47:06
03:47:07 This is line 2 03:47:07
03:47:08 This is line 3 03:47:08
03:47:09 This is line 4 03:47:09
This is line 5
03:47:10 This is line 6 03:47:10
03:47:11 This is line 7 03:47:11
This is line 8
```